# Подключение php файлов к wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Существует форма для заявки пользователя , где указан атрибут action = "handler.php". Как подключить handler.php к сайту , изначально код вводился в плагине на сайте , но там не указано по этому поводу ничего

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ - поместите файл в папку темы и обращайтесь к нему следующим образом:

```
 action = "<?php get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/handler.php"
```

Comment: а json файл туда же помещать?

Comment: Смотря какой json и для чего

Comment: Есть json файл , которых хранит в себе данные , откуда handler.php получает обьект с помощью decode

Comment: Ну тогда можно поместить его в ту же папку и формировать путь аналогичным образом - через `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.